# Oracle error: expression '' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to execute the stored procedure, all the parameters that I pass to it, appears "expression '(parameter)' cannot be used as an assignment target", I don't know what the problem is.

This is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSTERT_UPDATE_EMPLEADO 
(
  CEDULA IN OUT INTEGER,
  ID_CARGO IN OUT INTEGER,
  ID_EMP IN OUT INTEGER,
  NOMBRE IN OUT VARCHAR,
  APELLIDO IN OUT VARCHAR,
  FECHA_NAC IN OUT INTEGER,
  FECHA_CON IN OUT INTEGER,
  SALARIO IN OUT INTEGER
) AS 

BEGIN
  IF ID_EMP = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO EMPLEADO("CEDULA_EMPLEADO", "ID_CARGO", "EMPLEADO_ID", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDO", "FECHA_NAC", "FECHA_CONTRATO", "SALARIO")
    VALUES (CEDULA, ID_CARGO, ID_EMP, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, FECHA_NAC, FECHA_CON, SALARIO);
  ELSE
    UPDATE EMPLEADO SET NOMBRE = NOMBRE, APELLIDO = APELLIDO, FECHA_NAC = FECHA_NAC, FECHA_CONTRATO = FECHA_CON, SALARIO = SALARIO,
           CEDULA_EMPLEADO = CEDULA, ID_CARGO = ID_CARGO WHERE EMPLEADO_ID = ID_EMP;
  END IF;

  COMMIT;

END INSTERT_UPDATE_EMPLEADO;
```

Comment: You might need to qualify the column names, e.g. `UPDATE EMPLEADO SET EMPLEADO.NOMBRE = NOMBRE ...` etc

Comment: A lot of people prefix their local variable names with a letter, like `P_CEDULA IN OUT INTEGER,` to avoid this kind of problem

Comment: The problem is that the parameter names in your procedure are the same as the names of the columns in your table, as shown in the UPDATE statement. PL/SQL is confused by this. Change the parameter names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to insert or update the table, you need to create the table first.

If you already have the table, please ignore this step:

```
create table EMPLEADO 
(
  CEDULA    NUMBER(5),
  ID_CARGO  NUMBER(5),
  ID_EMP    NUMBER(5),
  NOMBRE    VARCHAR2(20),
  APELLIDO  VARCHAR2(20),
  FECHA_NAC NUMBER(5),
  FECHA_CON NUMBER(5),
  SALARIO   NUMBER(5)
)
```

Then create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSTERT_UPDATE_EMPLEADO(
  P_CEDULA IN EMPLEADO.CEDULA%TYPE,
  P_ID_CARGO IN EMPLEADO.ID_CARGO%TYPE,
  P_ID_EMP IN EMPLEADO.ID_EMP%TYPE,
  P_NOMBRE IN EMPLEADO.NOMBRE%TYPE,
  P_APELLIDO IN EMPLEADO.APELLIDO%TYPE,
  P_FECHA_NAC IN EMPLEADO.APELLIDO%TYPE,
  P_FECHA_CON IN EMPLEADO.FECHA_CON%TYPE,
  P_SALARIO IN EMPLEADO.SALARIO%TYPE)
IS 
BEGIN
   IF P_ID_EMP = 0 THEN
     INSERT INTO EMPLEADO("CEDULA_EMPLEADO", "ID_CARGO", "EMPLEADO_ID", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDO", "FECHA_NAC", "FECHA_CONTRATO", "SALARIO")
     VALUES (P_CEDULA, P_ID_CARGO, P_ID_EMP, P_NOMBRE, P_APELLIDO, P_FECHA_NAC, P_FECHA_CON, P_SALARIO);
   ELSE
     UPDATE EMPLEADO 
     SET NOMBRE = P_NOMBRE, 
         APELLIDO = P_APELLIDO, 
         FECHA_NAC = P_FECHA_NAC, 
         FECHA_CONTRATO = P_FECHA_CON, 
         SALARIO = P_SALARIO,
         CEDULA_EMPLEADO = P_CEDULA, 
         ID_CARGO = P_ID_CARGO 
         WHERE EMPLEADO_ID = P_ID_EMP;
  END IF;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in the procedure itself, but in its interface. `out` and `in out` parameters write their values back as output. For example:

```
create table demo (id integer);
```

Procedure (creates without errors):

```
create or replace procedure insert_demo
    ( id in out demo.id%type )
as
begin
    insert into demo (id) values (id);
end insert_demo;
```

Call fails, because the literal value `1` can't be updated with the `out` value returned by the procedure:

```
SQL> exec insert_demo(1)
BEGIN insert_demo(1); END;
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 19:
PLS-00363: expression '1' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

If you are going to use `out` or `in out` parameters, you have to pass variables (SQL*Plus example below, though you could just call it from another procedure passing a normal PL/SQL variable):

```
SQL> var id number
SQL> exec :id := 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> exec insert_demo(:id)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    

        ID
----------
         1
```

The solution is therefore either to pass variables, or to change the parameter mode to `in`:

```
create or replace procedure insert_demo
    ( id in demo.id%type )
as
begin
    insert into demo (id) values (id);
end insert_demo;
```

Test:

```
SQL> exec insert_demo(1)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It is generally good practice to avoid using column names for PL/SQL parameters and variables, for example by prefixing parameters with `p_` and local variables with `l_`. Or if you must, you can use dot notation and the procedure name, e.g. `insert_demo.id` or `instert_update_empleado.salario` would specify the procedure parameter and not the table column. However, that is not the cause of the issue here.

(Also, your caps lock is on.)